# Redirecting specific sites to HTTP in WordPress Multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect, https, http

What I need to do is redirect only some of the sites in my multisite installation to use HTTP instead of HTTPS. Currently my setup has been so that every site redirects to HTTPS but I can't seem to figure out how to force only some sites to go over HTTP. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I tried before actually worked but my browser forced the site to https from old habits (cache). If anyone else is having problems with this, here is what I did:

- Make sure the URL does not have **s** in it in your Sites page in Multisite Dashboard
- Make sure you don't have a plugin installed forcing HTTPS on (I had iThemes Security so I had to disable the SSL option from there)
- Make sure you change all the URLs in the database from https to http for the specific site (use a plugin like Better Search Replace that has support for changing serialized data and take backup of your database before doing it!)
- If you're still getting redirected to https, make sure you don't have antivirus program installed that checks SSL certificates (I had Bitdefender's option on to check for SSL certificates)
- After doing all of the above, try with different browsers and/or devices and everything should work now